# Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 undetected by BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I just mounted a new system few weeks ago. To make a short story, I had an old external IOMagic drive that I decided to put in my system for backup. The hard drive is a Barracuda 7200.10 250 GB with a 3.AAC firmware. Since it is an IDE drive, I bought a little converter to SATA. The drive is working (I hear it turning at least) and the card seem to be working fine. However, the disc goes undetected by the BIOS (and by Windows 7...). I've tried changing the jumper position and completely removing it but it does not work...

Any idea on this issue?

Here is my converter: http://www.ebay.ca/itm/260759758979?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649

Comment: By "undetected" you mean the channel shows up in the device manager with nothing attached to it?

Comment: Most of those piggyback sata converters do not work very well if at all, this is the only one that works well (at least that I have found)... http://www.datoptic.com/ide-host-to-dual-drive-ide-and-sata-adapter-bridge.html

Comment: A pci IDE card is the best choice, but are more expensive

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In the BIOS I can see my 4 SATA 3GB/s. Two have nothing plugged but three are written "unavailable"

Comment: What kind of converter?  By "changing the jumper position" which modes did you actually try (Master, slave, single)?.  Do you know if that "old" drive can be detected in a system with a native PATA ("IDE") controller?

Comment: @techie007 I updated the post to show the converter. I tested "cable select", "master" and no jumper at all. I don't know if it can be detected in older systems, but it works through USB (in its former case).